# Realated Apache Kafka producer and consumer part

Tags: apache-kafka

Is it possible to send a message from a Java producer into a Kafka topic and consume the same message from same topic through a python consumer?

I'm only able to produce and consume data from python but I want producer data from java in Kafka topic and want to consume data through python consumer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, sending a message from any language producer to a Kafka topic is possible, and then consuming the same message from the same topic using any language consumer. In your case Java and python respectively.

Comment: Can you tell me how can I do that?

Comment: @AnkitSingh Create a new question with code that you've actually tried and any errors you are running into

Comment: @AnkitSingh follow offical doc for kafka library for java and python - try to run it by yourself and then only we can help

Answer (score 1):

> I want producer data from java

That's exactly what `bin/kafka-console-producer` built-in script does. It is a shell command wrapped around Java code.

If you can consume those records from your existing Python consumer, that's exactly what you are asking for.